# Взаимодействие webview приложения и бд

Tags: php, webview, cordova

Создаю cordova wibview приложение и мне нужно подключить к нему бд, как это сделать?

---

Для обыного сайта я делаю это, например, так

```
<?php>
header('Location: ../ok.html');
  // Параметры для подключения
  $db_host = "localhost";
  $db_user = "root"; // Логин БД
  $db_password = ""; // Пароль БД
  $db_base = 'userData'; // Имя БД
  $db_table = "common"; // Имя Таблицы БД

  // Подключение к базе данных
  $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base);

  // Если есть ошибка соединения, выводим её и убиваем подключение
  if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
      die('Ошибка : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
  }

  $result = mysqli_query(" SELECT * FROM common");
  msqli_close();
<?>
```

---

Но как быть с приложением?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать AJAX запросы, т.к. внутри cordova приложения нельзя исполнять php фалы.
Вот пример:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#singup').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'singup.php', //тут ссылка на файл на сервере 
      data: $(this).serialize(),
    })
    return false;
  })
});
```

В фале singup.php находится нужный php код (типа того, что в вопросе), а сам файл соответственно находится на сервере